# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for

Tags: java, jdbc, intellij-idea

If I'm using maven plugin and through that everything works well, but how can i run it without Maven plugin using Run configuration and set up Tomcat from there. If I do some the following error appears:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db1
```

Using plugin everything works: **Maven Projects -> tomcat7 -> tomcat7:run**

[image]

But the problem occours when I try to run the same project through different run configuration like this:

[image]

Error comes from marked line:

[image]

The problem is probably related with the run configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java requires a database driver to connect to any kind of database. Depending on the database you are using, just include the driver dependency in your project and that will work.

You may ask that how SQLException occured without any driver/database dependency. That is a Java exception and you will find more information here

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html

As explained in the docs, there should be an implementation of the driver class and that is the problem you are facing.

Comment: If I use plugin then then how is driver dependency included to the project? Does plugin do that?

Comment: Can you add the plugin dependency you are using to the question?

Comment: AFAIK, that doesn't bring any driver dependency to the project. Either way, including an explicit driver dependency will solve your problem. I don't know why it runs with the plugin and why it doesn't with another configuration

Answer (score 1):

The maven Tomcat plugin probably loads an embedded tomcat with all libraries on the initial class path. When you deploy a WAR to an existing Tomcat, then the libraries of your application will be part of the context class path of the deployed web application.

The JDBC 4 automatic driver loading only works when the driver is on the initial class path. If the driver is on the context class path, it cannot be found automatically, and you need to load it manually to get it registered with `DriverManager`.

You can load the driver using

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
```

When the driver class gets loaded, it will register itself.